# Passing path parameter into power shell script using batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to pass in a path variable --> param ([string]$w) into another parameter that store the path in power shell script. Then this power shell script is called using another batch file. I failed to pass in the $ which is the folder name that completes the full path . Please suggest me solution on this

```
$FilePath = "C:\Root\Main\Subfolder\param ([string]$w)\Table\" 
$FileExists = Test-Path $FilePath 

  If ($FileExists -eq $True) 
     { Get-ChildItem -path C:\Root\Main\Subfolder\param ([string]$w)\Table\ -Recurse -Filter *.sql |
      ` Sort-Object -Property DirectoryName -Desc | `
      Foreach-Object -Process {$_.FullName } |ForEach-Object {sqlcmd -i $_}
     }

  Else {Write-Host "No file at this location"}
```

This is my batch file command line

```
 PowerShell.Exe -File C:\Users\AZ\Desktop\PowerShell\untitled7.ps1 "Payment"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this at the top of your script:

```
param(
        [Parameter(
                    Mandatory=$true,
                    Position=0,
                    HelpMessage='Set path variable')]
        [string] $w
)
```

Replace:

```
param ([string]$w)
```

with:

```
$w
```

where it appears in your script.